# MongoDb and morphia password and username

Tags: mongodb, morphia

playing around with this and cannot get a grip
on how to connect with password.

In MongoDb it's quite easy to understand but when i use morphia it's not
so quite obvious because documentation is minimal or i missed it.

I already have a Collection with 5 documents.
Can i apply a user/pass on that one?

How can i modify this code so logging uses a username and password?

Took the code from this post (Thanks @Lennart Koopmann)
[MongoDB Java driver tutorial](http://www.lennartkoopmann.net/post/722935345)

```
public final class MongoConnectionManager {

 private static final MongoConnectionManager
 INSTANCE = new MongoConnectionManager();
 private final Datastore db;
 public static final String DB_NAME = "mongo_database";

 private MongoConnectionManager() {
            try {
                Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            db = new Morphia().map(UserData.class)
     .map(Statistic.class)
     .map(FriendList.class)
     .map(ServerData.class)
     .map(BatchData.class).createDatastore(m, DB_NAME);

                db.ensureIndexes();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing mongo db", e);
            }
        }

        public static MongoConnectionManager instance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        public Datastore getDb() {

            return db;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
createDatastore(m, DB_NAME, username, password)
```

[This](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/source/browse/trunk/morphia/src/main/java/com/google/code/morphia/Morphia.java?r=1607#156) overloaded method has been introduced [here](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/source/diff?spec=svn574&r=574&format=side&path=/trunk/morphia/src/main/java/com/google/code/morphia/Morphia.java).

Maybe you are using older Moprhia client?

Comment: Not sure this is my jar morphia-1.00-SNAPSHOT.jar.
Nice will try that code. But i dont have a pass/user on the Collection now. Will Mongo just insert it and then the collection is always password protected? (no going back)

Comment: According to [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication) document currently you can configure security on a database basis (not collection).

Comment: mm.. yes i meant database of course, it can hole many collections ok got it

Comment: FYI This is now deprecated (as of 2014-02) and the username/password is ignored without warning... causing your app to suddenly fail to authenticate for no reason.

Answer (score 8):

maybe you could use the following code:

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress("host", 27017);
List<MongoCredential> credentialsList = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
MongoCredential credentia = MongoCredential.createCredential(
    "username", "dbname", "password".toCharArray());
credentialsList.add(credentia);
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(addr, credentialsList);
datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, "dbname");
```