# Morphia / Java how to pass in username and password in new version?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

per [MongoDb and morphia password and username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828098/mongodb-and-morphia-password-and-username) , the constructor allowing username and password is now deprecated. How do I specify username and password then? I'm trying to connect to a username/password enabled mongoDB.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828098/mongodb-and-morphia-password-and-username

Answer (score 1):

You would create your MongoClient and pass in the appropriate credentials using the constructor shown [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/MongoClient.java#L139-139).

Comment: To complete the answer - as far as I understand the corresponding mechanism for db.createDatastore(client, db, username, password) is using MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(username, db, password) and using that when creating the client.